# About CRUD generator in Yii

Tags: yii, crud, scaffolding

i am starting to use Yii framework and the gii tool to create the crud functionality for several tables.

The issue is that i need normally to modify the generated code. For example, i have noticed that all the forms use only text inputs. For example, in the case of foreign keys i need to show a select where the user can select a register of the other table without having to insert the primary key.

I achive this modifying the involved views (_view.php, _form.php, ...). My problem starts when it's necessary to modify the database and regenerate the code again. For that case i would have to go table by table, updating the involved files one by one keeping my old changes.

Does it exist a way to deal better with this situation?

Answer (score 2):

The [GiiX extension](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/giix/) generates dropdowns for relationships.

In case you use the Gii Model generation, GiiX generates better models, too.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to do that. You can generate a select with the foreign keys, for example.

```
<?php echo CHtml::dropDownList('ModelName[language_id]',$model->language_id,CHtml::listData(Language::model()->findAll(), 'id', 'name'), array('prompt'=>'Select Language')); ?>
```

The first parameter is the name of the select, second is the value (if you're updating, the value will be selected), third is the data, and the fourth is an array with html options. More info about [CHtml::dropDownList](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml/#activeDropDownList-detail) and [CHtml::listData](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#listData-detail).

In this, the `language_id` is the foreign key, and in the `Language` table you have an `id` and a `name` field. This will generate a select with all the available languages, like this : 1=> English, 2=> German etc.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am doing that modifying the views of the generated code. But if i have to regenerate the crud code, these changes would be overwritten no?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can select which files are re-generated, this way you can avoid overwriting modified ones. I believe there is even a color change, if a modification was detected.

Comment: Yes you are right, but if for example i add more columns to a table i am forced to rewrite the affected file

Comment: If you can't implement the changes manually, then yes, you are forced to rewrite the affected file.

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to need the functionality of crud form generation a couple of times, with the option of show foreign keys as dropdowns, you can create your own gii template to do it for you. [Take a look at the guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.gii#extending-gii) to know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

For this functionality you need to develop you gii tool which will inherit functionality of existing gii tool, means some modification in existing classes while creating CRUD. This is your specific requirement, gii tool provides only general functionality which suits to all users.

Comment: Thx to everyone i'll have a look on the gii guide about extending its functionality

Comment: this has already be done in the giix extension. See my answer.